# creating rpm using sbt native packager for scala play app

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt native packager (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) to create rpm for the scala play application. I followed the instruction to run the command `sbt rpm:packageBin`. However, it builds the `.jar` file, is this the rpm build? I thought the rpm build should be .rpm extension?

I did get error but I am still able to see the `.jar` file

```
[info] Done packaging.
[error] `rpmVendor in Rpm` is empty.  Please provide a valid vendor for the rpm SPEC.
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: There are issues with the rpm spec data.
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmSpec.validate(RpmMetadata.scala:154)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmHelper$.stage(RpmHelper.scala:25)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$47(RpmPlugin.scala:158)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (rpm:stage) There are issues with the rpm spec data.
```

Comment: Can you include your build.sbt to your question?

Comment: I did not make any changes on build.sbt for rpm. But I added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.4")` in plugins.sbt. I'm able to see `/target/rpm` folder but cannot see `.rpm` file

Answer (score 1):

Play Framework requires some additional settings for rpm. This is documented [here in the Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#minimal-rpm-settings).
For simplicity I copy the relevant part here:

Minimal RPM settings

Add the following settings to your build:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

maintainer in Linux := "First Lastname <first.last@example.com>"
packageSummary in Linux := "My custom package summary"
packageDescription := "My longer package description"
rpmRelease := "1"
rpmVendor := "example.com"
rpmUrl := Some("http://github.com/example/server")
rpmLicense := Some("Apache v2")
```

Then build your package with:

```
[my-first-app] $ rpm:packageBin
```

Finally you should have `projectname-projectversion.rpm` eventually under target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/ -folder (or something similar).

Comment: What does `rpmUrl` mean? `rpmUrl := Some("http://github.com/example/server")` means the server we want to post the rpm? I want to publish the rpm to artifactory.

Comment: The official description says that  "the Url should have the full URL for more information about the program. Most often this is the upstream project website for the software being packaged", https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/ . Even if it's just for internal use, it would be nice to have link to some internal wiki or git -page that tells what the packaged rpm is about.

Answer (score 0):

After your comments I would say you need to add more information in your build.sbt file.

Your project should include data about the rpm. There are lots settings [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html) you can use, but the bare minimum is to add rpmVendor to your build.sbt like this:

```
rpmVendor := "VendorName"
```

If you need examples, take a look at some on [Github](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples).

Comment: I have to use `rpmVendor := "typesafe"` according to the doc? I don't know what vendor really means here. I want to publish the rpm to artifactory

Comment: The definition of vendor is the name the company or organization behind an RPM